# First Run of Maven Built Application in IntelliJ fails

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a project that I want to build with Maven but run with IntelliJ, i.e. not delegate run actions to Maven. I have an Application Run Configuration that points at the main class of my project, with a Before Launch action of `1. Run Maven Goal 'Project Name: compiler:compile'`. The FIRST time only that I run this config, I get:

> Error: Could not find or load main class xx.Main
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xx.Main

And on subsequent (using the exact same run config) runs, it works perfectly.

Note: if I have a separate Maven Build Target for my project and I run that first and then the Application Run Target (without the build before launch), it works first try. I've also tried setting a Before Launch action to run that Build Target, with the same failure as a result. This ONLY occurs when I try to build and run in the same target.

It seems like IntelliJ is caching the build state BEFORE anything runs and then using that same state AFTER the Maven Build has run... Does anyone know why this occurs and if there is a way to fix it, or am I just stuck running it twice after every clean? Happy to provide more detail if required.

Background as to why I want to do it one step: I'm setting this up for some very junior (and VERY prone to messing things up) devs and the fewer steps there are, the better. I don't want them to have to think about how to make it run.

Comment: I can reproduce this. One thing that works for me is to also run the Intellij Build task as a before launch action. Either before or after the maven goal seems to work.

Comment: Have you raised a ticket with Intellij?

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you! This workaround works for me. I haven't raised a ticket yet as I wasn't sure if it truly is a bug or if there was some configuration option that I was missing or something. The fact that you can reproduce it is probably confirmation enough that I should raise a ticket, so I will do so. Thank you again!

Comment: And maybe make the maven target `package` so the tests get run?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? Relevant info as others potentially encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by tgdavies in a comment, it's possible to make this work first time by adding an IntelliJ Build task following the Maven Build task in the Before launch steps. My Main Run Target now has Before launch: `1. Run Maven Goal 'Project Name: compiler:compile'` `2. Build`. Obviously this solution is less than ideal but at this stage, I'll take functional. I'll be raising a ticket with IntelliJ and hopefully it will be addressed... Thanks tgdavies!